# Performing match by index lookup with cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a dense node problem and to get around this I've been using indexing to perform some matching using the native Java API, but I've been giving Cypher a second look and wanted to know if this could be done. Currently my pattern looks like this in Java Code:

```
Node startNode = db.getNodeById(1);
Index<Relationship> relationshipIndex = db.index.forRelationships("relationships");

for(Relationship relationship1 : startNode.getRelationships(Direction.OUT)) {
    Node otherNode = relationship.getOtherNode(startNode);
    String indexValue = (String)otherNode.getProperty("indexValue");
    for(Relationship relationship2 : relationshipIndex.get("indexKey", indexValue)){
        Node endNode = relationship.getOtherNode(startNode);
        //Processing on the endNode
    }
}
```

How would I translate this to cypher? Something like:

```
START startNode=node(1)
MATCH startNode-[r1]->otherNode
WITH node:relationships("indexValue:" + otherNode.indexValue) as r2
RETURN r2.endNode //Notation for getting node off relationship?
```

I don't really see anywhere to just get a relationship, then get the end node through a relationship like this.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, in 2.0 there's a startNode(rel)/endNode(rel) function, but it's not there for 1.9 or earlier.

http://console.neo4j.org/r/4807s7

So in theory you could do this:

```
start rel=rel:rel_auto_index(indexKey="value") 
with endNode(rel) as n
match n-->m
return *
```

And that would avoid ever touching the startNode of the relationship (unless there's a pointer back to it from `n`).

Comment: Could you do the index lookup outside of the start? I've updated my code to show what I mean, but I do a traversal on the first part, then the relationship index lookup.

Comment: Apparently not. There is actually a feature request for that: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/93 and https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/389

Comment: That's what I assumed, I updated the question again to reflect in Cypher kind of what I'd like, but but it looks like the open issue also wants what I'm asking for.