# Combining two neo4j cypher calls into one call

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following two cypher calls that I'd like to combine into one;

`start r=relationship:link("key:\"foo\" and value:\"bar\"") return r.guid`

This returns a relationship that contains a guid that I need based on a key value pair (in this case key:foo and value:bar).

Lets assume r.guid above returns 12345.

I then need all the property relationships for the object in question based on the returned guid and a property type key;

`start r=relationship:properties("to:\"12345\" and key:\"baz\"") return r`

This returns several relationships which have the values I need, in this case all property types baz that belong to guid 12345.

How do I combine these two calls into one?  I'm sure its simple but I'm stumbling..

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305200/performing-match-by-index-lookup-with-cypher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer I've gotten is that there is no way to perform an index lookup in the middle of a Cypher query, or to use a variable you have declared to perform the lookup.

Perhaps in later version of Cypher, as this ability should be standard especially with the dense node issue and the suggested solution of indexing.

Comment: I agree, as I need it as well, however look for it in future versions and just use something like Gremlin or the native Java API for now.